# Refresh 2 divs with one click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay,
So I want to refresh 2 divs with ONLY 1 CLICK OF 1 BUTTON without actually refreshing the page itself.

I've tried the following

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <a>
        <div id="dialogue" class="dialogue">
            <b class="dialogue">Click to continue</b>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded

    $('#dialogue').click(function(){

        $('#main').load('dialogue.php?test&count=<?php echo $count ?>', function() {
            /// can add another function here
        });

    });

    $('.dialogue').click(function(){

        $('#head').load('dialogue.php?head', function() {
            /// can add another function here
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

This in the HTML: `<div id="dialogue" class="dialogue">`
needs to activate 2 div refreshes, I did this so i can hook two things up.
The following scripts just bugs out and can only refresh itself once instead of a couple of times, please help.

Comment: You can only refresh once because of the way the HTML is nested. If you reload the main div, everything inside of it will be refreshed including your trigger.

Comment: Where is the div #head? I found the question unclear...

Comment: @colecmc - can you clarify your statement? I don't see any issue with firing both of the `$.load()` on the one `$.click()`?

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ - Based on the html, I think the contents are being wiped out after 1st click.

Answer (score 2):

You can call multiple functions inside the single click event, like so:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // click event
    $('#dialogue').click(function(){

      // refresh first element
      $('#main').load('dialogue.php?test&count=<?php echo $count ?>', function() {
        // callback
      });

      // refresh second element
      $('#head').load('dialogue.php?head', function() {
        // callback
      });

    });
  });
</script>
```

Since `#dialogue` is a child of `#main`, and you're replacing the contents of `#main` on click, the `#dialogue` button will disappear once clicked.

---

<s>A minor note: your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<div>` element (which is block-level) inside an `<a>` (which is inline). Try this markup instead:</s>

```
<div id="main">
  <a id="dialogue" class="button-dialogue">
    <strong>Click to continue</strong>
  </a>
</div>
```

Looks like HTML5 allows `<a>` elements to wrap lots of other stuff now. Thanks to [Mathletics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7469/mathletics) for the correction.

Comment: As of HTML5, [you can wrap an `a` around just about anything](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having:

```
$('#dialogue').click(function(){
```

You could use:

```
$('#main').on('click', '.dialog', function(){
```

So the listener of the clic is attached to parent, and will work on new '.dialog' elements added inside of it.